# Efficient multi-queue iteration

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

> We are given a subroutine which takes two positive int arguments and returns an int, let's say it's `def f(m,n): return (m+n)**2-n**2`.  The input values must be positive integers.  The returned value is increasing with respect to both of the inputs: that is `f(m,n)<f(m+1,n)` and `f(m,n)<f(m,n+1)` for all `m` and all `n`.  We want to iterate over all possible pairs of `m` and `n` in an order that gives the returned values in increasing order, until it passes a test.  We don't care about the test: we know some pair of values will pass it, and we want the smallest returned value which passes.  We also don't know if the test will be passed in the first million values of `m` and `n` each, so we can't just build the entire list of values and sort it.
>
> How do we iterate over `m,n` in the correct order, reasonably efficiently?

I visualize this as a multi-queue, which can't be the right name: what is it called?

I have an array `nextN[]` indexed by `m-1`, storing the largest visited `n` for that `m`. Another array `nextV[]` indexed by `m-1` stores the returned value of `f(m,nextN[m-1])` so we don't call `f()` more than once for any pair (this can be omitted as a pre-optimization, but it's a necessary optimization when `f` takes a long time to run or has side effects).  At each step we take the smallest stored value and test it, and update those elements in the two arrays with the next value of `n`.

The question is: what data structures and methods should be used to make this multi-queue efficient and understandable?  I have the quick hack, but I want a better, more understandable and maintainable solution.

I'm writing in Python, but the same question applies to Java, C, etc.  Give your answer in whatever language you like.  (I won't select an answer in a language chosen for its obscurity, but I will +1 it if I can understand it and it's helpful.)

Here is some sample code:

```
from array import array
from math import sqrt

def findSmallestV(f,test):
    # initialize with m,n=1,1 filled out
    nextN = array('I', [1])
    nextV = array('I', [f(1,1)])
    while True:
        v = min(nextV)
        m = nextV.index(v)+1
        n = nextN[m-1]
        if test(v):
            return (m,n,v)
        nextN[m-1] += 1
        nextV[m-1] = f(m,n+1)
        # if we've just operated on the last column, put a value into the next column
        if m == len(nextN):
            nextN.append(1)
            nextV.append(f(m+1,1))


# example value function
def g(m,n): return (m+n)**2-n**2

# example test function
def h(v): return len(str(v))>5 and int(sqrt(v))**2 == v

ans = findSmallestV(g,h)
print("Smallest V: m=%d, n=%d -> %d" % ans)
```

I feel like this will spend a long time on `min(nextV)` when the size of `nextV` gets large.  What's the better way?

Comment: I would suggest figuring out the recurrence relation. In your example, if you know f(m,n), then you can calculate (using simple algebra) that f(m+1,n) = f(m,n)+2m+2n+1 (assuming I did it right), and similarly, f(m,n+1) = f(m,n)+2m. So, adding 1 to m always increases the answer by more than adding 1 to n. You should be able to exploit that information to help derive an algorithm... Probably using something like a priority queue, where you can insert new values in places other than just the ends...

Comment: It's not always (actually, almost never) possible to derive a recurrence relation.  This example used a trivial `f` to make it easy to grasp, but most functions are not so simple.  However -- the idea of using a priority queue may be the winner here.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is break the problem into two steps:

1. Find some (m, n) that passes the test.
2. Use a binary search technique to find the lowest (m, n) that pass.

You could potentially use a binary search technique for the first part, too.

It's hard to know what "passes the test" means. Do you know if the returned value is too large or too small? If so, you can adjust `m` and `n` by halving or doubling until you find a solution.

Given your restrictions (i.e. the relationships you described), the binary search on two variables shouldn't be too difficult.

You can keep track of intermediate passing values in a priority queue. So when you find one that passes you can put it on the queue. That can be the starting point for your next time through. You'll also want to keep track of the highest and lowest passing values that you've found, so that you can more easily bracket the search.

And, I suppose, you'll want to keep a hash table of some kind that will prevent you from generating the same `(m,n)` more than once.

This becomes easier if `m` and `n` have some defined range. If it's "all positive integers," the technique I describe is possible, but it's a lot easier if they're bracketed.

Comment: Passing the test is only known as true or false, there's no "warmer, cooler" available.  1 `m,n` pair in about 15 million (in my current actual real world problem) passes the test, so finding the ones that pass is a bigger problem than testing in increasing order.

Comment: @JeffSnider: In that case, the binary search test isn't going to help.

Answer (score 1):

A priority queue, as suggested in the comments, leads to a good solution.

At any point during the running of your algorithm, you will have considered some points and not considered others. You'll put the points on the boundary of this divide into a priority queue. More specifically, you maintain a priority queue (probably implemented as a binary heap) of triples (m,n,v), sorted by v, where (m,n) is a point on this boundary and v its value.

At every iteration, extract the lowest valued point from your queue and test it. If it passes, it's the answer. If not, put the points to its right and above it into your queue, together with their values.

This will work as is, but it's inefficient, because every point gets processed many times. To prevent this from happening, also maintain growable arrays of the lowest coordinate in every column that's in your queue, and an array for the leftmost entry in every row. Whenever you would enter a point into the queue, first check if there's already a lower point in that column or a point further to the left in the same row. If so, just don't enter it - it'll come later anyway.

Comment: This is largely what I've done.  Thanks for the answer.